# Removing redundancy between those two functions?

Tags: python

I feel like there is a redundency between:

```py
def _determine_nodes_with_no_predecessors(nodes:List[Node])->List[str]:
    """
    Given the list of nodes returns the identifiers of nodes that doesn't have any predecessor. 
    """
    nodes_ids_without_prdecessors = []
    for node in nodes:
        if not node.predecessors: 
            nodes_ids_without_prdecessors.append(node.id_)
    return nodes_ids_without_prdecessors
```

And this one:

```py
def _determine_nodes_with_no_successors(nodes:List[Node])->List[str]:
    """
    Given the list of nodes returns the identifiers of nodes that doesn't have any successor. 
    """
    nodes_ids_without_successors = []
    for node in nodes:
        if not node.successors: 
            nodes_ids_without_successors.append(node.id_)
    return nodes_ids_without_successors
```

How to write less code in this case? Is it possible to write only one function? I thought about adding a bool as an argument, something like `START = True` and then write in if-else statement, but I don't know if it's clean.

Comment: It is possible to put it all in one function. For example like you said with a boolean flag to decide whether to look for successors or predecessors. In my opinion, those functions should stay separated, because they serve different purposes and with if-else statements in there, it is going to be quite messy.

Comment: @Carcigenicate the first one it looks for nodes without predecessors whereas the other one looks for nodes without successors. Each node has two attributes `predecessors` and `successors`.

Comment: @CodingClown what do you think about the answer of Carcigenicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to generalize this, you could pass in a accessor function. There are multiple ways to do this, but a simple lambda would suffice:

```
def _determine_nodes_with_no_using(nodes: List[Node], accessor: Callable[[Node], List[Node]])-> List[str]:
    """
    Given the list of nodes returns the identifiers of nodes that doesn't have any successor. 
    """
    nodes_ids_without = []
    for node in nodes:
        if not accessor(node): 
            nodes_ids_without.append(node.id_)
    return nodes_ids_without
```

Then

```
_determine_nodes_with_no_using(nodes, lambda node: node.predecessors)

_determine_nodes_with_no_using(nodes, lambda node: node.successors)
```

You could also use the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
from operator import attrgetter

_determine_nodes_with_no_using(nodes, attrgetter('successors'))

_determine_nodes_with_no_using(nodes, attrgetter('predecessors'))
```

Comment: `predecessors` and `successors` are lists of objects of type `Node`

Comment: This is beyond my knowledge, I don't know neither about `Callable` nor about `lambda`

Comment: @PatrickK. `Callable` is a type hint indicate that something is a function (or rather, that it's "callable"). `lambda` is pretty fundamental to Python though. That's an anonymous function.

Comment: Yup, I didn't know that we can pass a function as a parameter to another function! This is great. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, functions are first class in Python. They're objects that can be passed around like anything else.

Comment: What do you mean by functions are *first class* in Python?